# How to prove the trigonometric identities of sin/cosine series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, trigonometry, fourier-series

I found two triangle identities about the sum of cos/sine.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {\cos \left( \frac{2\pi \Delta}{N} n \right)} = 0,  {\quad \rm for\ }\Delta = 1, 2,\cdots$$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {\sin \left( \frac{2\pi \Delta}{N} n\right)} = 0,  {\quad \rm for\ }\Delta = 0, 1,\cdots$$

For the second identity, I feel much easier to accept in an intuitive way when examing the special case $\sin (\frac{2\pi}{N}n) = -\sin (\frac{2\pi}{N}(N-n))$ (i.e., when $\Delta = 1$). For the first identity and the second one in a more generalised condition (any $\Delta$), I didn't have a clue.

Comment: Use the fact that the sum $\sum_{k=0}^N e^{i 2\pi k/N} = 0$. It is geometric sum ,you can calculate it easily, if you need help don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: cheers! I got it

Answer (score 1):

What you can use is Euler's formula and deal with a sum of exponentials instead, like so :

$$e^{i \frac{2 \pi n \Delta}{N}} = \cos{\frac{2 \pi n \Delta}{N}} +  i \cdot \sin{\frac{2 \pi n \Delta}{N}}$$

Then your sums become:
$$Re(\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} e^{i \frac{2 \pi n \Delta}{N}}) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {\cos \left( \frac{2\pi \Delta}{N} n \right)}$$
and 
$$Im(\sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} e^{i \frac{2 \pi n \Delta}{N}}) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} {\sin \left( \frac{2\pi \Delta}{N} n \right)}$$
respectively. The sums are now easy to deal with geometric sums.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive derivation!

Comment: You're welcome :)